# Using the MATCH statement in NebulaGraph database fails

Tags: nebula-graph, opencypher

I have NebulaGraph database version 3.1.2 running in my AWS environment and I am testing basic openCypher.

If I run `MATCH (n:Person{lastName:"Brown"})-[e:LIKES_COMMENT]-(m) RETURN m.locationIP`, it fails to retrieve the user IP. Not sure where it went wrong. It should be a valid openCypher statement and Nebula Graph supports openCypher.

Simply returning `m` works. Screenshot is as follows:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it propmpted, we should use var.TagName.PropName like

`m.Comment.locationIP`

This is one of where it differentiated from the vanilla OpenCypher in NebulaGraph.